# Linear regression for time-series prediction

Tags: regression, time-series, lasso, ridge-regression

Say we have $N$ time series $X_t^i$ for $i=1...N$and we want to predict a separate time series $Y_t$. Let's consider the following model: $Y_t = \sum_{i} \beta_i X_{t-1}^i $

I am just trying to figure when such a model makes sense

- Does this model have a name? Is there an interpretation in terms of random processes? Are there any known applications?
- Does it make sense to solve the $\beta_i$ by using regression approaches (ridge, lasso, etc) using the training points $(<x_{t-1}^1... x_{t-1}^N>, y_t)$?

Comment: you are purposely not including a constant in the regression? Usually a Beta_0 is included.

Comment: Are you familiar with [tag:var] (vector autoregression)? That sounds a lot like what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at this as a problem in [least squared minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).
so you're trying  to minimize:

$$ \langle \epsilon^2 \rangle_t= \langle ( Y^t - \sum_i \beta_i X^{t-1}_{i})^2 \rangle_t = \langle (Y_t - \vec{\beta} \cdot X^{t-1})^2 \rangle_t$$

I tend to interpret this type of problem as a Gaussian statistics problem since the solution only involves first and second moments.  The idea is that there is a Gaussian joint distribution for $p(y, x_1, x_2 \dots)$ with an arbitrary correlation matrix;  you are trying to estimate that correlation matrix, and then computing the conditional distribution $p(y \vert X)=p(y,X)/p(X)$.

In some contexts, this type of problem may be referred to as a [Wiener Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter) problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer, but just to add something for completeness in relation  to whether this model is used anywhere:

If you in addition would assume each $X_i$ to follow an AR(p) process, then your model is one of the most commonly used for analyzing predictability of stock returns in the financial econometrics literature. See for example [Stambaugh (1999)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=205390), which led to a lot of other research on this model by noticing the bias of the OLS estimator of $\beta$ in such settings. More recent papers include [Chen and Deo (2009)](http://ideas.repec.org/a/cup/etheor/v25y2009i05p1143-1179_09.html) and [Amihud et al. (2010)](http://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/empfin/v17y2010i3p513-525.html).